# Self-Evaluation: Why cutting an 'X' into ammunition?

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

I want a way to properly answer self evaluation in a way that exceeds the comments section so here it is.

In terms of the general audience, it would seem someone would choose to say bullet or bullets over `ammunition` (even if used incorrectly)

[image: Google Trends for ammunition, bullet, bullets]

From there, I choose to remove the `Why` portion as one would be looking for a definition. How can I phrase this, for me, I would rather search for

> Apple computers

versus

> Where can I buy apple computers

Maybe this isn't how most users search and I think it should be something to be considered but for the moment I am going to assume I am the norm.

Leaving the verb `cutting` and letting Google do auto-complete for popular searches starting with this we get the following

[image: Google search]

So we have two search terms to look for

- cutting x in lead bullets
- cutting x in bullets

We are going to assume these searches are ordered by popularity and choose

> cutting x in lead bullets

I will use the answer to block to place my self-evaluation based on this query.

Comment: Note I have given examples for others as well even though my conclusion is that the above query is the most likely one to be used.

Comment: Doh, I should've used bullets in the text. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Why cutting an 'X' into ammunition?`

`http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Why+cutting+an+'X'+into+ammunition%3F`

Search: "high position"
Answer: "good answer"
Result: **better**

Answer (score 0):

`cutting x in lead bullets`

`http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cutting+x+in+lead+bullets`

Search: "no position"
Answer: "good answer"
Result: **worse**

Answer (score 0):

`cutting x in bullets`

`http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cutting+x+in+bullets`

Search: "iffy position"
Answer: "good answer"
Result: **par**

Answer (score 0):

`cut x into bullets`

`http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cut+x+into+bullets`

Search: "no position"
Answer: "good answer"
Result: **worse**

Answer (score 0):

`Why does Travis cut his bullets`

`http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Why+does+Travis+cut+his+bullets`

Search: "no position"
Answer: "good answer"
Result: **worse**

Answer (score 0):

`Why does Robert De Niro cut his bullets`

`http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Why+does+Robert+De+Niro+cut+his+bullets`

Search: "iffy position"
Answer: "good answer"
Result: **par**

Answer (score 0):

`cut x into ammunition`

`http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cut+x+into+ammunition`

Search: "no position"
Answer: "good answer"
Result: **worse**